# how to change text color in bootstrap-cue

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Want button on dark-blue background with white text

code in xxx.vue

```
 <b-dropdown text="user" right variant="blue" class="signout-button">
    <b-dropdown-item @click="toMain()">sign out</b-dropdown-item>
 </b-dropdown>
```

and style is

```
.bg-blue {
}
.signout-button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #183450;
  border-color: #183450;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

the result look like this

[image]

it still back text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example should do the job, as b-dropdown will generate that button tag inside.

```
.signout-button button{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need styling on the `<b-dropdown>` compiles it converts to `button` tag.

```
.signout-button button {
  color: green;
}
```

Here is working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/4wm0pah3/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: it work on change dropdown-item but I want to change color on dropdown (b-dropdown tag)

Comment: Glad I can able to help you!